# Not able to post with PHP Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

I am using **TwitterAPIExchange** to publish tweets to Twitter. Over the last 4 months I had no problems until I switched from **HTTP** to **HTTPS**.

I did not think this would be a problem as I do not even see this as a setting within the Developers APP and I am doing all this through crontab.

I am using the identical code below on two different servers and the one with SSL I get a successful connection (no errors) but no posting of the tweet -- meanwhile on the server without SSL I get a successful connection and a successful post.

Can a IP get blocked and if so, how do I check it if is, or is SSL a problem -- what do I need to do to fix this?

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$connection = array('oauth_access_token' => 'xxx', 'oauth_access_token_secret' => 'xxx', 'consumer_key' => 'xxx', 'consumer_secret' => 'xxx');
try {
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($connection);
    echo 'Connection success <br /> ';
    $response = $twitter->buildOauth('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json', 'POST')->setPostfields(array('status' => 'Test Tweet'))->performRequest();
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    if (!empty($json['id_str'])) echo 'Post success: '.$json['id_str'];
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Given that this is happening via CLI, the HTTPS/HTTP nature of the server it's on has nothing to do with it. What does the response JSON show?

Comment: The successfully one has data the unsuccessfully one comes in blank -- no errors, nothing.

Comment: What does `var_dump($response)` show?

Comment: Got it, SSL need to be turned off since I am now using it. CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false

Comment: Hang on, that's not your server's HTTPS, that's Twitter's HTTPS. Disabling cURL's verification makes you vulnerable to attack. Figure out why your server isn't accepting Twitter's SSL certificate. Is this server ancient?

Comment: No and they have this as an answer on the TwitterAPIExchange web site.

Comment: That doesn't make it any less dangerous. Turning off certificate verification gets rid of the entire point of having SSL. [Stop turning off CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and fix your PHP config](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/)

Answer (score -1):

Added `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` to **TwitterAPIExchange**